# Ansible Inline module is not taking variable?

Tags: ansible, airflow

I have below code, but it is not working as there is variable in the "line" module. Please let me know if I need to create a path at the run time and insert in the fstab. how it is possible?

```
  lineinfile:
    dest: /etc/fstab
    line: "{{ bucket_name }}" "{{ airflow_home }}/dags"  gcsfuse rw,allow_other,uid=1004,gid=1005,dir_mode=777
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote the whole *line* expression. If the *dest* does not exist you can *create* it.  Correct syntax is below

```
- lineinfile:
    dest: /etc/fstab
    line: "{{ bucket_name }} {{ airflow_home }}/dags gcsfuse rw,allow_other,uid=1004,gid=1005,dir_mode=777"
    create: true
```

Comment: if you use moustache expressions ( like `{{ bucket_name }}`) you need to quote whole line @gaurav agnihotri

Comment: Yes. See [YAML syntax requires that if you start a value with {{ foo }} you quote the whole line,](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#hey-wait-a-yaml-gotcha)